# Reading the property file with annotation in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting problem while i am reading the property file with annotation in spring framework.i try same program with xml its working fine but problem in that also is i am checking file is available in class path its giving false.the code is as follow.my exception is

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfigMongoDB': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public java.lang.String gettingValueFromResourcePropFile.AppConfigMongoDB.name; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driverClassName' in string value "${jdbc.driverClassName}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
```

The code is:

```
package gettingValueFromResourcePropFile;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class SpringConfiguration {

    public SpringConfiguration(){
        super();
    }

  @Bean
  public static PreferencesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PreferencesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }

}


@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class AppConfigMongoDB { 

    @Value(value="${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    public String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

 }


public class MainContainer {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("db.properties");

        final File file = new File(url.getFile());
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());


        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfiguration.class);
        AppConfigMongoDB mongo = applicationContext.getBean(AppConfigMongoDB.class);
       System.out.println("== ==" + mongo.getName() ); 


    }

}
```

my property file is available in src and problem is i am unable to read the properties file(prop file includes following property)

db.properties file

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver 
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://production:9002
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=root
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the property file.

Comment: think you are following this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

Comment: If the file is not in the classpth... then make sure it is. How are you building and running your app? What is the directory/file structure of your project?

Comment: Rajith pemabandu  I followed that link the example is working fine but if I create seperate configuration file then the same error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define a single properties file

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:default.properties")
public class RestAPIURLConfig { … }
```

or

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:default.properties")
public class RestAPIURLConfig { … }
```

or

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"file://D:/SpringExamples/default.properties"})
public class RestAPIURLConfig {}
```

When We define property files using “classpath” as shown in above examples, it searches that file at project classpath and resolve all values.

**To define multiple properties file**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:default.properties","classpath:config.properties"})
public class RestAPIURLConfig {}
```

NOTE:

When we define multiple property files using `@PropertySource` annotation, then order of those files is very important. For instance, take above example. If we define same property(key-value) pair in both default.properties and config.properties files, then config.properties overrides default.properties value.

### So the project structure looks like below:

[image]

### **Resource Link:**

A full example with step by step is described in [this tutorial](http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-properties-with-propertysource-annotation/).

Answer (score 0):

> my property file is available in src

I believe you need to put your `db.properties` file under `<project_home>/src/main/resources`, this is the `classpath` of resources for most Java build tools.